# Connecting to specific clients in a chat app

Tags: javascript, redis, chat

Im making a simple chat app that sends messages through a redis pub/sub channel. I do not use any login options just lets the user select a username and chat. I am trying to implement private chat where one client is able to communicate to another connect client. I am new to chat client programming, I am trying to figure out how to communicate with only one client. What are some options I could consider to get the ability to chat 1 on 1? I don't mind changing my architecture to incorporate a new tool. Any suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with raw sockets. I held user objects which contained the connected socket, the name, and whether they are chatting.  If a user is not in chat he can type a command `/list users` which gives the list of users currently connected. When he has found someone to chat with he enters the command `/chat bob`. If the user `bob` is already chatting he will receive a message from the server saying that `bob is in a chat already`. Otherwise a chat session will be established between the two users. They now will be in chat until one of them enters `/endchat`. Then they will be able to find new people to chat with.

The trick is implementing the server so it can track a list of users and their chatting status and who they are in chat with so when ever they type `/endchat` the other user can be notified.

Comment: Thank you I think that concept works. I was wondering how did you create the user object and how do you get the socket to send from one user to one? Also, I was looking into Ratchet but I am not sure how to implement redis pubsub with ratchet. I need to use redis subscribe to receive messages. Thats what held me back from ratchet

Comment: I m able to list the usernames of currently connected user. Where I am stuck is, when u say /chat bob, how do u send that message only to bob and not everyone connected?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Nodejs + Socket.io would solve your problem i suppose. Specifically rooms functionality is what you are looking for here.

Lets say you have two users bob and gob. Considering both are online (although you can add Redis as a session store and for storing history later, which i did in my case). Say bob wants to chat with gob he selects gob. Now make bob join a room using

```
 var roomname = 'bob'>'gob'?'bob'+'gob':'gob'+'bob' ;
 //this type of naming ensures roomname is same for both users
 socket.join(roomname);
```

This will work only if both have chosen each other. So now when gob selects bob both are joined in the same room. Whenever someone sends a message make them emit to that room using

```
 socket.broadcast.to(roomname).emit('message_event',msgObj);
```

Make sure you have have added the listener

```
 socket.on('message_event',messageHandler);
```

When chat is finished make them leave the room using

```
socket.leave(roomname);
```